# two simple forms, why I can't submit the one I want?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

The two simple forms I have looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@class_room, :html=>{:id=>'class_room_form'}) do |class_room_form|
```

and

```
= simple_form_for(@lesson, :html => {:id=>'lesson_form'}) do |lesson_form|
```

now, although I am submitting form of id lesson_form, form with id class_room_form is submitted instead! any idea what to do ?

here is how I submit the lesson_form form:

```
:javascript
  $('#submit_lesson_button').bind('click', function() {
    $("#lesson_form").trigger('submit');
    });
```

here is how I submit the other form ( the one that is still submitted regardlessly )

```
:javascript
  $('#submit_button').bind('click', function() {
    $('#sidenav a:first').tab('show');
    $('#class_room_form').trigger('submit');
    });
```

you see, each form with different ids, and I am targeting those different ids with jQuery, so what could be wrong ??

notice that form `lesson_form` is contained within form `class_room_form`

Comment: Please add a comment to the accepted solution to indicates what you did. It will help future visitors.

Comment: I've solved the problem by putting the contained form outside, both forms are on the same level of the DOM tree, this has fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to have a form contained is another form. If you can change this, it will certainly solve your problem, and your code will be cleaner.

If you can't, try to add `event.preventDefault()` to your functions, like this :

```
:javascript
  $('#submit_lesson_button').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#lesson_form").trigger('submit');
  });

:javascript
  $('#submit_button').bind('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#sidenav a:first').tab('show');
    $('#class_room_form').trigger('submit');
  });
```

I suppose `#submit_lesson_button` and `#submit_button` are `<input type="submit" ... >`